# Help with query Illegal assignment from List<Group> to Id

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to update Owner where the  group name is equal to the custom metadata Mayor Name and the custom metadata city is equal to the custom object city. I am currently stuck how to get the group id to update the owner.

```
trigger CityCensusTrigger on City_Census__c (before insert, before update) {
    Map<String, Mayor_Mapping__mdt> getAllMayors = Mayor_Mapping__mdt.getAll();
    
    for(City_Census__c c: Trigger.New) {
        for(String mayor : getAllMayors.keySet()) {
            if(c.City__c != null && c.City__c == getAllMayors.get(mayor).City__c){
                c.OwnerId = [Select Id From Group Where Type='Queue' and Name =:getAllMayors.get(mayor).Mayor_Name__c];
            }
        }
        if(c.Auto_Approve__c == true){
            c.Approval_Status__c = 'Approved';
        }
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you can guarantee you find a record, just add `.Id` after the `]` of your static SOQL. I would not personally assume I can find a single record though. (You always get back an SObject or SObject list, not just the one field's value.)

Comment: soql in a for loop, let alone a nested for loop is really bad practice - easy to imagine hitting governor limits. Read up on apex bulkification